# No startup sound

Tags: sound

Despite numerous attempt, and advise, this is what I applied.

```
sudo cp /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/* /usr/share/sounds/
```

---

Type this:

```
cd /dev 
ls -l |less 
find 14, [0-...]
```

This file for audio you can type

```
cat /etc/passwc >/dev/dsp 
dsp if speaker device
```

This is not a big deal but I'm an OCD person, so I would like that it works. An other issue is the screensaver, I can not watch movies.

I understand that Ubuntu default settings are "Turned off start up sound, and 10 min screensaver auto"

If I would be allowed to a suggestions, it is the followings: Is that so problematic to create a check box to check or un check this futures, just to be able to enjoy your product fully? Furthermore I'm reading a lot of similar issues on blogs... Annoying